# Is there RELATIVE_PATH, like ABSPATH

Tags: urls

`ABSPATH` outputs like  `C/:docs/http_root/public_html/`  or `/home/userXXXXX/public_html` (or etc, depending on server).

However, I want to get the file location according to its relative path from `ABSPATH`. How to achieve that?

i.e. I want to get from file:

```
C/:docs/http_root/public_html/some_folder/file.php
---->
/some_folder/file.php
```

P.S.

1) `request_uri` and `php_self` wont help in this case.

2) Maybe it's surprising but even this doesn't help on all servers:  `str_replace(ABSPATH, '', __DIR__)`

Comment: You can use realpath with str_replace maybe. http://php.net/manual/tr/function.realpath.php

Comment: @SerkanAlgur see my comment under the ^Chin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with [__FILE__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to get the location of the current file.

```
str_replace(ABSPATH, '', __FILE__);
```

So for example if `__FILE__` returns:

```
/users/chin/public_html/project-name/wp-content/theme/theme-name/functions.php
```

The output would be:

```
/wp-content/theme/theme-name/functions.php
```

Comment: thanks but it has many problems (like on windows hostings it replace wont happen, because the slashes have different directions (i.e. `/` and `\` ). But I created helper function to convert any direction slashes in `/`. so, finally used that solution as i told myself..

Comment: Can't you just replace those slashes with something like `str_replace('/', '\\', __FILE__);`

Answer (score 1):

The question is relative path to what?

themes and plugins do not have to be located in the wordpress directory tree, therefor there is no obvious "root" to be relative to.

Side note: I am not sure I ever seen a case in which using a relative path over an absolute one is a good idea.

Comment: yes, i know you havent seen probably. i am just including dynamic path-ed file in wp-config.php, while ABSPATH is not yet defined. I will release that plugin soon, named "enable WP DEBUG from admin dashboard"

Comment: If I understand correctly what is it that you want to do, it is unlikely to work well users needing to edit wp-config is always a problematic idea and in some environments (bitnami which I think is based on bedrock), non technical users are unlikely to be able to figure easily out the locations.of the plugin directory.

Comment: or in other words, you will have to either assume that your plugin is in standard install, or try to figure the type of install first

Comment: can you tell me a bit more details about what you mean in "type of install"? i havent thought about them?

Comment: look how the file structure ofbedrock is structured - https://roots.io/bedrock/ . In theory you can detect such a structure in your code